# Overwrite MKMapView, how to deal with Delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

I have a created a custom class that extends from MKMapView and i want to use the delegate methods inside that class so i do in my init function super.delegate = self.

Now i can receive delegate methods inside that custom class, But how do i get double delegation, if I implement this class, how can i receive my delegate methods in there also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom class can provide it's own delegate property.  Then in it's implementation of the delegate methods it can invoke the message on the extra delegate property.

For example:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    //do your custom code
    //...
    //then call the delegate
    [self.extraDelegate mapView:mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:animated];
}
```